# Counting all possible combinations in a given list of list

Tags: python, list, combinations, combinatorics, counting

I have a list of list as `list_1 =[[A,B,C,D],[A,D],[B,C,D]]`. I would like to have an output such as:

[image: Required Output]

So as shown above I expect the Count of all possible combinations that are present in the list of list.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please [edit] to include your expected output in the text of your question, not as an image, to make a [mcve]. Please also show what you have tried so far based on your own research, and what went wrong with your attempt(s). For example, [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html), loops, etc

Answer (score 0):

try use this wich will loop over all the lists & count all possible combinations in this list using [itertools.combinations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) and Add the number to `result`

```py
import itertools

list_1 =[["A","B","C","D"],["A","D"],["B","C","D"]]
result = {}

for sublist in list_1:
  for L in range(1, len(sublist)+1):
    for subset in list(itertools.combinations(sublist, L)):
      key = "".join(list(subset))
      if key in result:
        result[key] += 1
      else:
        result[key] = 1
```

and if you want to print them:

```py
for item in result:
  print(item + " => " + str(result[item]))

# Output:  
#         A => 2
#         B => 2
#         C => 2
#         D => 3
#         AB => 1
#         AC => 1
#         AD => 2
#         BC => 2
#         BD => 2
#         CD => 2
#         ABC => 1
#         ABD => 1
#         ACD => 1
#         BCD => 2
#         ABCD => 1
```